# use post method in php mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a form which gets email ID from the client and executes a php file on submitting the form.

The php script will send a mail to the obtained email id along with a link to remove the email ID from the database.

I used 'post' method in the html form to obtain the email ,but I don't know how to use the post method in the email too.

my html form code :

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
     <input type="text" name="e1">
     <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

send.php file :

```
<?php
      $to = $_POST['e1'];
      $message = 
        ' /* added a html mail along with remove email link */

          <a href="mydomain.com/remove.php?data=".$to.>Click to remove</a>

          /* Here in the hyperlink to the remove.php ,I have to use post method instead of using '?data='....' get method */
?>
```

Inside remove.php I have the sql query to remove the $to email . As anyone can use enter data for the '?data=' in the URL, I have to use post method

How can I do it a simple/safer way?

Comment: just fyi, anyone malicious enough can edit POST data just as easily. What you really need is proper server-side data validation.

Comment: you can't do POST with a `<a>` click clink. that just does a GET. you'll need to have another `<form method="post">` in your email, pointing back at the server hosting the remove script.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but are you trying to post a form from within an email? Or are you trying to make an "unsubsribe" link and send it as POST?